# How to use GROUP BY for multiple columns in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am working on existing project which is developed on Laravel + Mysql. Now, I have migrated my database from Mysql to Sql server. So all the queries written in project using Mysql syntax.

Now, I have an query given below:

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_3.date as sem1date 
FROM table_1, table_2, table_3 
WHERE table_3.ID=table_2.DID AND block_datelu.BID=table_1.final_exam_date AND table_1.centreid=1234 AND table_1.course=1 
GROUP BY table_1.start_date, table_1.end_date
```

When I am converting above query into sql server syntax, then sql server giving me error msg "**Column 'table_1.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**"

Can anyone tell me how can I use group by for multiple columns having joins?

Comment: Better you use the modern explizit join instead of the implizit join

Comment: You can only select values wich are in the Group by clause or aggregated values. So in your case `select table_1.start_date, table_1.end_date , max( table_3.date) as sem1date 
....`